# Finding list of bus stop transfers in bus traffic

Tags: java, line, between, bus

Let's say I have a list of lists of every possible transfer between two bus lines.

```
[a,b]
[b,a]
[b,c]
[c,b]
[b,e]
[e,b]
[c,e]
[e,c]
```

I want to go from a -> e

Wanted results:

```
[a,b,c,e]
[a,b,e]
```

You can read the above as:

```
[a,b]
[b,e]
a -> b -> e = [a,b,e]
```

**If I went c->b, i can't go back (b->c)**

What's the easiest way to get those lists of transfers?

Comment: You can save your arrays (the path between tow station) as 2D matrix and then use multiple algorithms that find the path between two nodes in the matrix.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-whether-path-two-cells-matrix/

Answer (score 0):

1. Do create a graph of stations. You can use [Adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) or [Adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)
2. Then use [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to find all possible ways from one vertices to another.